# Getting path of the file that saved on Sharepoint Document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, file-upload, path

Hoe to get the full path of the file that saved on into sharepoint document library. I have one requirement, in this if i upload one file to the document library, then i want to save the Doc path of the same to the DB. please help me to implement this task. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some code to ItemAdded event handler and deploy it as a feature:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties pobjSPItemEventProperties)
{         
    using (SPWeb objSPWeb = pobjSPItemEventProperties.OpenWeb())
    {
        string strFileUrl = pobjSPItemEventProperties.ListItem.File.Url;
        //save to DB here
    }
}
```